# View Pushed many times from didSelectRowAtIndexPath master detail VC ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem where same view is pushed many times on selection of a row and if user keeps on clicking on the same row it crashes.

MasterDetailVC.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LAClaimReport *record = [_claimReports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([record.submitted isEqualToNumber:@1])
    { // if i click on clicking here VC is getting pushed and pushed. 
        [self.detailViewController showReadonlyViewForClaimReport:record];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.detailViewController showEditViewForClaimReport:record];
    }
}
```

LADetailViewController.m

```
   @interface LADetailViewController()
    {
        LAClaimReport *_claimRecord;
    }
-(void) showEditViewForClaimReport:(LAClaimReport *) claimReport
{
    _claimRecord = claimReport;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEditView" sender:self];
// calls LAClaimReportViewController
}

-(void) showReadonlyViewForClaimReport:(LAClaimReport *) claimReport
{

    _claimRecord = claimReport;


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toReadonlyView" sender:self];
// calls LACreateReportViewController.

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toEditView"])
    {
        LAClaimReportViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.claimReport = _claimRecord;
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toReadonlyView"])
    {
        LACreateReportViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.claimReport = _claimRecord;
    }
}
```

`LAClaimReportViewController` & `LACreateReportViewController` are two diff. VC having segues from `LADetailViewController`. I want that the VC (`LACreateReportViewController` or `LAClaimReportViewController`) should not be pushed many times on multiple click of the same row of the masterDetailVC. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the View is already pushed. If it is then don't push it again. If its not pushed then push it.

For this you can make a instance variable may be a bool. Lets call it isPushed. Make `isPushed = true;` when you push the view. When you pop it then make `isPushed = false;`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LAClaimReport *record = [_claimReports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([record.submitted isEqualToNumber:@1] && !isPushed)
    { // if i click on clicking here VC is getting pushed and pushed. 
        isPushed = true;
        [self.detailViewController showReadonlyViewForClaimReport:record];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.detailViewController showEditViewForClaimReport:record];
    }
}
```

The above is just an way. One thing is this: `[record.submitted isEqualToNumber:@1]` always false? If it is then you would like to check that I think.

Hope this will Help.

Comment: This approach will not work. I have row1 & row2. both should performs the push but if any single row is pushed more than once then it should not push VC multiple times. In this approach , it will block any other row to push the segue.